# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement (vb.net)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I receive an error when I run my project in vb: [syntax error in insert into statement]

```
Private Sub Bsimpan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bsimpan.Click
    If Tno.Text = "" Or Tnis.Text = "" Or Tnama.Text = "" Or Tkelas.Text = "" Or CBjk.Text = "" Or Tt4lahir.Text = "" Or ttgllahir.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Data Belum Lengkap")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call koneksi()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from Anggota where nis='" & Tnis.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If Not rd.HasRows Then
            Dim sqltambah As String = "insert into Anggota(No,nis,Nama,Kelas,Jenis_kelamin,Tempat_lahir,Tanggal_lahir) values " & _
                "('" & Tno.Text & "', '" & Tnis.Text & "', '" & Tnama.Text & "', '" & Tkelas.Text & "', '" & CBjk.Text & "', '" & Tt4lahir.Text & "', '" & ttgllahir.Text & "')"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqltambah, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Call kosongkan()
            Call tampilkan()
            Tno.Focus()
        Else
            Dim sqledit As String = "update Anggota set " & _
                "NIS='" & Tnis.Text & "', " & _
                "Nama='" & Tnama.Text & "', " & _
                "Kelas='" & Tkelas.Text & "', " & _
                "Jenis_kelamin='" & CBjk.Text & "', " & _
                "Tempat_lahir='" & Tt4lahir.Text & "', " & _
                "Tanggal_lahir='" & ttgllahir.Text & "'"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqledit, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Call kosongkan()
            Call tampilkan()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Building up the query string via concatenation always opens you up to syntax errors, in addition to SQL injection risks. Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: Can you provide the value of sqltambah after the concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parametrized queries.

For example the query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO anggota 
            (no, 
             nis, 
             nama, 
             kelas, 
             jenis_kelamin, 
             tempat_lahir, 
             tanggal_lahir) 
VALUES      (@no, 
             @nis, 
             @nama, 
             @kelas, 
             @jenis_kelamin, 
             @tempat_lahir, 
             @tanggal_lahir)
```

Then adjust your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", Tno.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nis", Tnis.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama", Tnama.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kelas", Tkelas.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jenis_kelamin", CBjk.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tempat_lahir", Tt4lahir.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tanggal_lahir", ttgllahir.Text)


cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqltambah, conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: No, nis, Nama, Kelas, Jenis_kelamin, Tempat_lahir, Tanggal_lahir  these are 7 columns in insert query

Comment: @meda where do i write that code cmd... is in values?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a character in your values that could create an invalid sql statement.  However, generating an sql statement with a concatenation of user inputs is a very dangerous and evil thing to do because it open the door to a simple, well known and well documented security issue called SQL Injection.

The only good way to handle parameter is with parameterized SQL query.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a missing space between the table name and the first parenthesis?

Probably the best way to find out would be copy the content of the `sqltambah` variable and run the insert statement yourself and see if you get a little more info about where the error is.

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: missing space is not a syntax error, no problem with that